# Angular 6 Http request fails with authorization headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, tomcat

I'm deploying and **angular** 6 application that works with a **tomcat** server in **localhost**, when I try to execure this http request

```
this.http
      .post<LoginResult>( API_URL + '/login', JSON.stringify(json)/*, { headers: myHeader }*/).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('get-token', []))).subscribe((response) => {
      if(response['result_code'] == 'result_ok') {
        this.auth.doSignIn(response['token'], response['name']);
        this.router.navigate(['user_manager']);
        return true;
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

everitying works well, but when I add header field

```
let myHeader = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", 'Basic' + this.session.getAccessToken());

    this.http
      .post<LoginResult>( API_URL + '/login', JSON.stringify(json), { headers: myHeader }).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('get-token', []))).subscribe((response) => {
      if(response['result_code'] == 'result_ok') {
        this.auth.doSignIn(response['token'], response['name']);
        this.router.navigate(['user_manager']);
        return true;
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

this is my output error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8095/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
HttpErrorResponse
```

I checked also that the request doesn't arrive to my tomcat server, it is blocked before, that oesn't allow angular to check response headers

Thank you for your help

Comment: Couple of things: There is no need to `JSON.stringify` your payload, as Angular does this for you. Just pass the actual object. Also, you have no space between `Basic` and the token value.

Comment: Thank you but doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

**I'm providing you a generic answer as you have not mention that your server side code is written in which language.** 
 You should provide a header from your server code. Provide `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with value as `localhost:4200` which will resolve your issue. Or if you want to allow every origin then change its value from `localhost:4200` to `*`.

After reading all the comments I have change something for you.

change your this code `let myHeader = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", 'Basic' + this.session.getAccessToken());` with `const myHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('api_token')});`
 and make your post request as

```
this.http
      .post<LoginResult>( API_URL + '/login', json, myHeader).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('get-token', []))).subscribe((response) => {
      if(response['result_code'] == 'result_ok') {
        this.auth.doSignIn(response['token'], response['name']);
        this.router.navigate(['user_manager']);
        return true;
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure CORS on your tomcat server.

You need to tell tomcat which headers the application is allowed to send, so it can include it in the preflight response:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Authorization,Content-Type,...</param-value>
</init-param>
```

**Take a look at**

`cors.allowed.methods` under CORS Filter section here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html

Comment: Can you help me in where I have to puth theese lines?

Comment: Hmm I've never used tomcat, but you will need to find the config file, what is your OS?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: do you know the tomcat installation directory? If yes then, `TOMCAT-HOME/conf/server.xml` and `TOMCAT-HOME/conf/web.xml` are supposedly the config files. You may have to search both of them for `cors.allowed.methods`

Comment: Yes, I have to put it on web.xml?

Comment: I'm not sure. Like I said, never used tomcat and a little rusty with windows. So you will have to open both the files and do a text search. web.xml sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184591/discussion-between-aravindan-ve-and-alesandro-giordano).

Comment: Hi I've resolved the problem, it is when angular call the TomCat server he does an OPTION request to obtain the cors headers, but I've not handled any option request on my server so I set cors headers only in a GET or POST request